# route method becomes undefined in main package file

Tags: go, martini

My code is as shown below :

app.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
)

func main() {
    app := martini.Classic()

    app.Group("/books", func(r martini.Router) {

        r.Get("/:id", getBooks)
        r.Post("/new", newBook)
        r.Put("/update/:id", updateBook)
        r.Delete("/delete/:id", deleteBook)
    })

    app.RunOnAddr(":8080")
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import "github.com/go-martini/martini"

func getBooks() string {

    return "get books api called"
}

func newBook() string {
    return "Psot book api called"
}

func updateBook(params martini.Params) string {
    return "put api called " + params["id"]
}

func deleteBook(params martini.Params) string {
    return "delete api called " + params["id"]
}
```

But somehow when I run the code , it gives me the following error :

`./app.go:16:17: undefined: getBooks
./app.go:17:18: undefined: newBook
./app.go:18:24: undefined: updateBook
./app.go:19:27: undefined: deleteBook`

So is there any way to solve this problem?

the project structure is as follows:

```
goProject
---->app.go
---->main.go
```

Comment: Both `app.go` & `main.go` need to be in the same directory which doesn't seem to be the case since `main.go` is under the directory `controller` where `app.go` isn't.

Comment: Which directories are the two files in?

Comment: @Flimzy I have updated the question in which I have mentioned the structure

Comment: Thanks. The problem is indeed exactly as @Abdullah described. Those two files must be in the same directory to be part of the same package.

Comment: @Flimzy I have put the file in the same hierarchy ,still issue is the same

Comment: Alternatively to the other suggestions, you can *export* the handlers, import the package where the handlers are defined, and then reference the handlers with the package's name as the qualifier.

Comment: @MrugeshThaker hierarchy is not the same as directory.

Comment: Please read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: @MrugeshThaker What command do you use to run your app?

Comment: @MrugeshThaker also you should avoid naming all of your packages `main`.

Comment: @mkopriva I have updated the question for that

Comment: @Abdullah go run app.go

Comment: @MrugeshThaker that compiles and executes only the app.go file, ignoring the main.go file.

Comment: Exactly the problem. Use `go run ./...` instead.

Comment: @Abdullah it worked . If you can put it as solution which might help future readers.

Comment: Whoever told you to run your code via `go run` did you do a disfavour: Never use go run to run code (except if this is a one-file script). Build your programs with `go build` and than execute them. If this is too enterprisey: Write yourself a make file which emulates what go build does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

#### #1

You need to have both files in the same directory with the same package name; namely, `main`.

#### #2

You need to compile and execute all files in this directory which you can do either using:

- `go run ./...` to execute all files in this directory, or,
- `go run app.go main.go` to execute just these two files.

---

Alternatively, as suggested by @mkopriva, you can move and export all handler functions to a different package, let's call it `package handlers` and just import this package in your `main` app.