# How to import routes

Tags: go

I just started a Go project by following the tutorial on Pluralsight, but I experienced a bit of an obstacle when I wanted to *separate* all of my routes into *one file route*.

Previously my code went well:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*.html")

    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Helo from %v", "Gin")
    })

    r.GET("/json", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H {
            "status":  "posted",
            "message": "Hi...",
            "nick":    "Nick here",
        })
    })

    r.GET("/template/index", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", nil)
    })

    r.Run(":3000")
}
```

Until here, all of my code is **running well**.

Then I made a route file like this:

routes.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

func registerRoutes() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.LoadHTMLGlob("templates/*.html")

    r.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Helo from %v", "Gin")
    })

    r.GET("/json", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "status":  "posted",
            "message": "Hi broh",
            "nick":    "Nick here",
        })
    })

    r.GET("/template/index", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", nil)
    })

    return r
}
```

And I changed the code on my `main.go` to:

```
package main

func main() {
    r := registerRoutes()

    r.Run(":3000")
}
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
go build main.go
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:4:7: undefined: registerRoutes
```

I have tried to understand it but I always get that error message. Is something wrong with my code?

My project structure:

[image]

Comment: You are building a single Go file here so the compiler won't be able to link the required routes.go file resulting in the above error.
Try "$ go build" to create the binary and then execute it. Alternately, you can use "go install" as well.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi ok I'll try

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55260736/5198756) answer!

Comment: @BerthoJoris feel free to vote the answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need both things:

- Run your application with `go run ./...` or `go run main.go model.go routes.go`
- Rename your function `registerRoutes` to `RegisterRoutes`, to make your function public, and visible in your package

Comment: There is no need to export the function, it's all in the same package. It should be `go run .`, it doesn't make sense to give multiple package arguments to `go run` (which is what "./..." does).